# How to apply styles using styleSheet in react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-stylesheet

I am trying to apply some styles in my react native application but it's not working with me, I tried to run it in the browser this is the output showed up:
[image: browser output]

But when I run it in my phone it's showing me an error:
[image: phone output]

This is the main App.js file:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import HomeMenu from './src/screens/Home/index';

export default function App() {
  return (

    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <HomeMenu />
    </View>

  );
}
```

And this is index.js file (the one I want to show its results):

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const HomeMenu = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>   //add flex:1 here
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};
export default HomeMenu;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#21534A',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Comment: How do you know the styles are the problem? Your styles look fine.

Comment: then where's the problem ? can you help me figure that out? @Konstantin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:-

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const HomeMenu = () => {
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>  
  //add flex:1 here
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
);
 };
 export default HomeMenu;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#21534A',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
});
```

Comment: same problem nothing appeared

Comment: add `style={{flex:1}}` in main `View` of `app.js` as well.

Comment: when I did it it worked fine in my browser same as what I wanted but in my phone it's showing an error @Shan Alam

Comment: remove `//add flex:1 here` I did mention there just so that you can understand.